# How to make F5 shortcut key to run query on IBM Data Studio 4.1.1?

Tags: sql, keyboard-shortcuts, ibm-data-studio

F5 is shortcut to refresh on IBM Data Studio 4.1.1. How to make F5 shortcut to run SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

In Preferences, under General - Keys, you can see all the shortcut key mappings.

If you search for `F5` (in the box near the top) you will see all the functions mapped to that key.

`F5` is the default for Run SQL when in the default "SQL and XQuery" editor, so it should be working for you out of the box.

If you want to use another key for "Run SQL", click in the `Binding` box when the "Run SQL" line is highlighted, then press your desired short-cut.   Then press the Apply button.